# Jenkins got error after transfer file over SSH using scp

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh

On my remote server, there is a script that execute some .pkl files every 10 minutes. After I transfer some new (and different) .pkl files from local using ssh as below:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/<my_pem_file>.pem /my/local/location ubuntu@<ip> /my/remote/location
```

and push the updated script to branch master on github, Jenkins got the error:

**SOLVED:** It seems the server ran out of memory when the script executed

```
File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 507, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1181, in load_long_binput
    self.memo[repr(i)] = self.stack[-1]
MemoryError
SSH: EXEC: completed after 25,217 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [<my_server>] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

The new .pkl files which just have been transfered couldn't be executed. I set permission for those ones all the same. Do you have an explanation for this issue? Thank for your time anyway!

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the permission for execution to Jenkins? It seems to me that you are copying those files and setting "execution" rights but maybe you are not chaning the owner

Comment: Why don't you mention the `MemoryError` shown in your output?  Why is it not relevant?

Comment: @Alfe I've just inspected and it seems the server ran out of memory when the script executed. I think I have to optimize the .pkl files or upgrade the server's ram